# Consecutive serial number as SELECT MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, max

This is my table:

MyTable (Id, Name, Description, SerialNumber)

Id is an identity field and primary key.
SerialNumber is an int with a Unique index.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (
    Name, 
    Description, 
    SerialNumber
) VALUES (
    'SampleName', 
    'SampleDesc', 
    ISNULL(MAX(SerialNumber),0) + 1 FROM MyTable)
```

What are the cons of managing the serial number that way?
What is about the concurrence?

Comment: Probably the biggest con is that the SQL is not syntactically correct.  You probably want to look into sequences.

Comment: if Id is an identity field and primary key, it must be unique.  Why not use the Id field as the serial number?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't to use the identity as a serial number because of the gaps

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it has been done this way to prevent gaps in the numbers. With both sequences and identities you can't assume there will never be gaps, especially in case of rollback.

The problem you have with this is that there is a race condition and some of your inserts can end up in a error or your table can have duplicate serial numbers depending if the column is unique or not. This happens because it's possible that 2 processes fetch the max at the same time before either of them have inserted the number into the table.

Comment: JamesZ, now that you understand the case, what way do you prefer to deal with unique serial numbers?

Comment: I usually have separate table that contains numbers, if it can share numbers with other tables depends on frequency of usage etc. You can get the number by update XXX set @ID = NEXTID, NEXTID = NEXTID+1 where TABLENAME = 'MyTable'. To prevent gaps this has to be in same transaction as the insert.

Comment: And I think that in the same transaction you must increment NEXTID and update it in your table that contain numbers. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that's what the update statement in my previous comment was trying to show and it's a single update statement that fetches the number + updates the table to avoid deadlocks